# Function in R intended to be non-visible to end-users

Tags: r, package

When building an R package, I wrote several functions, but some of them are not very important so I plan to not document them and they're invisible to end-users. However, I use these functions in my Examples section, so they have to be included in the package (but not in the help doc list). I am not sure how to do that. Do I need to:

1. delete the documentations for that function (in Emacs, not using C-c C-o) so roxygenize won't generate .Rd files?
2. still wrote the documentations, but without @export?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Won't you confuse people by having hidden functions in your examples? I can't think of a good reason for it.

Comment: @Spacedman: some of the functions are indeed less important and will be used only in examples, or I just curious how to achieve this (maybe not used in my pacakge). Thanks!

Comment: Leave out the `@export` and roxygen wont generate documentation for it. Then add `@keywords` internal.

Comment: I completely agree with Spacedman.  If you need the function for one of your examples then it should be exported.  If you can't do what you want to do in your example without using one of your hidden functions... why is the function hidden if it provides functionality that you want to show off in an example that you can't do without it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not export those functions, you will need to call them with the triple colon construct:

```
myPkg:::myHiddenFn
```

There are some example of doing this in some of the base and 'Required' packages help pages.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your suggestions! Yes, I will export my function in the package. The reason I ask this question is that I saw some package authors wrote functions but some of them can only be accessible via `pkgName:::funName`. I think it's not good either, but just curious how people can achieve this :)

Comment: It's fine to write non-exported functions.  It just doesn't make sense (to me) to not export functions that provide some functionality the the user might want to use.  Or at least provides enough functionality that you want to display the use of that functionality in an example.  Writing non-exported functions in general is a good route to go to help break apart logic into smaller functions and then the user doesn't need to know how to use those smaller functions - they just need to know how to use the exported function that ties all of your little functions together.

Comment: @Dason: Thank you Dason for the comments! I've changed my code to export these functions to end-users :)

Comment: Have a look at what Duncan Murdoch [recently had to say about this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-September/064830.html)